# Alfresco CMIS unauthorized

Tags: liferay, alfresco, cmis

im doing an integration of Liferay and alfresco, my goal is to use alfresco 5.2 to store content created in Liferay DXP.

To do that ,i have added this line to portal-ext.porperties

```
dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portal.store.cmis.CMISStore
```

and added the config file `com.liferay.portal.store.cmis.configuration.CMISStoreConfiguration.cfg` with this content:

```
repositoryUrl=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom

credentialsUsername=admin credentialsPassword=password

systemRootDir=Liferay
```

Everything worked fine but suddenly im getting this error while rebooting liferay:

```
21:19:37,536 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][com_liferay_portal_store_cmis:97] [com.liferay.portal.store.cmis.CMISStore(1549)] The activate method has thrown an exception 
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisUnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:477)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:645)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getRepositoriesInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:808)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.store.cmis.CMISStore.createSession(CMISStore.java:591)
    at com.liferay.portal.store.cmis.CMISStore.activate(CMISStore.java:475)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:224)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:617)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:501)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:302)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.inject.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:294)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:297)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:906)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse$1.run(ServiceFactoryUse.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

What does  unauthorized mean in this context?

Comment: Make sure the username and password settings are on different lines, not one line as shown in your question!

Comment: I finally found the problem : alfresco SSO was active and was making the cmis url endpoint not allowed for users  outside SSO.